# How do I disable popups in PhraseExpress?

Tags: windows-7, notifications, notification-area, phraseexpress

Every time I launch a program with admin privileges, PhraseExpress shows a notification like this:

[image]

This can be very annoying. Since I don't want to run PhraseExpress with admin rights, is there a way to disable this type of notification? I have tried looking in the settings but I didn't find any option for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a screenshot of the settings dialog for turning off the bubble hints:

[image]

Comment: Of course I didn't find it, I kept looking under popups :)

Comment: We will improve the way, those notifications are shown and we will allow to click the bubble to disable them. Our apologies for the trouble you may have experienced.

Comment: No worries, thank you for the update, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

In PhraseExpress, please check Settings >> Dialogs to configure notifications.